# How to display a (DOM) message before following a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I just want to tell the user that the next operation (a click on a link) will take some time... (to avoid reloading the page and clicking again on a link).

I've tried:

```
<p id="message" style="display:none" class="notification">This could take a while, please sit down and relax</p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").click(function() {
        $("#message").show();
      });
    });
</script>
```

but the message, didn't show up. The click went through as expected.

Comment: use $("#message").style('display','block'); to show the message..

Comment: If 'the next operation will take some time' it's probably better to perform an (possible asynchronous Ajax) `POST` request instead, wait for success result, then redirect the user.

Comment: Maybe something like this: `window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        $("#message").show();
    }` - though I'm not really sure what's taking a while.  :)

Comment: @Lucky: makes no difference, also, I've tried it manually in the inspector and the .show() works.  However when I do a e.preventDefault(); the message shows up...

Comment: @sideroxylon: the link to be followed, gets a client listing with some stats per client, it takes about 23 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    $("#message").stop(true, true).show(250);
    $("#message").delay(2000).hide(250);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href = "#">test foo link</a>
<p id="message" style="display:none" class="notification">This could take a while, please sit down and relax</p>
```

Something like this ?

Comment: No, the problem is that I really want to follow the link and once the browser sees this, it doesn't display any changes to the DOM tree anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more cross browser (Safari, Chrome gave problems), using another event is better:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").on("mousedown", function(e) {
        $("#message").show();
      });
    });
</script>
```

works like a charm. Ofcourse they could exit the link when releasing the mouse, but on mouseup you get the same problems as on click.

if you realy want it 100%, you could hide the message on mouseup on document level:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").on("mousedown", function(e) {
        $("#message").show();
      });
      $(document).on("mouseup", function(){
        $("#message").hide();
      });
    });
</script>
```